# What is the difference between "Managing Nuget Packages" at the solution level in Visual Studio 2019 vs at the Project level?

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

I currently have a Nuget Package (MediatR) at the Solution Level (via Manage Nuget Packages for Solution).  I have a project that needs that package.  Do I need to install it also at the Project level?  When do you manage them at the Solution level vs. Project level?

Answer (score 7):

The "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution" shows an aggregate of all the projects. When installing a package, you must still select which projects to install them in.

It provides a convenient location to automatically update or install packages across multiple projects.

When you manage packages for a single project you get a project-only view.

How packages are installed is no different between the two options.

Comment: So when I add the NuGet package at the solution level, do I need to also add it at the project level?

Comment: No, that happens automatically, cause you select which projects to install into when installing at the solution level.